# Extract Attachments from Email VBA Script

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following VBA Script which I use to extract multiple attachments from multiple emails. But when I use it, the email is then left with a marker

[image: Email Screenshot]

I can see the point in the below script and wish to remove this, however when I do and try run again, I get a Compile Error.

[image: Compile Error]

What do I need to remove correctly to be able to run the script by leaving the marker?

```
        End If
        Next i
        If xSaveFiles <> "" Then
            If xMailItem.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                xMailItem.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & xSaveFiles & vbCrLf & xMailItem.Body
            Else
                xMailItem.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & xSaveFiles & "</p>" & xMailItem.HTMLBody
            End If
        End If
        xMailItem.Save
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Which line did the error occur? Your code in the question is incomplete as well, can you edit and post a complete code? And what is the *marker* issue? I don't see any *marker* in the screenshot so you might want to clarify that.

Comment: Just comment out everything from `If xSavefiles <> "" Then` to `xMailItem.Save`

Comment: Thank You @Tragamor your answer was exactly what I was looking for.